# extremely slow connection to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

I'm using a very simple connection to a localhost database:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://usr:pwd@localhost/db')
engine = engine.connect()
data = engine.execute('select * from table')
```

'table' has 500 lines. Then I run the cProfiler on 'data', where I find this:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
54086  127.261    0.002  127.261    0.002 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

here http://bugs.python.org/issue3766 it seems that it would be solved setting TCP_NODELAY to 1. My question is, where do I set this?

Comment: Out of curiosity how big is your table?

Comment: @GWW 500 lines... DUUUUH

Comment: @Neal: Clearly, I can't read.

Comment: @GWW and you call yourself a "PhD Student". **HA!**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is OK. The bug reports describes recv calls which take 0.02 seconds, yours is 1/10 of that. This is quite OK in my opinion. The reason it takes so long is that you make 54086 calls (108 calls per line). I would suggest you to rewrite the query so that the number of calls decrease. Ask what you want of your db.